# Python Tkinter: How do you loop through a list and display items on a new line in a new root

Tags: python, function, loops, tkinter

I am building a translation app using tkinter, and I am trying to get the translated results to appear on a new line in a new root window. So if the user translates

one

two

three

The new tkinter root window should show

uno

dos

tres

Here is the function that displays the translated words

```
def display_translated(text_to_trans):
    root2 = Tk() # new root window 
    root2.title('Translated text')
    root2.geometry('200x200')
    label2 = Label(root2, text='This is the translated text') # label to explain what the root window is showing 
    label2.pack()
    display_words = [] # list of empty words that will be appended with the list of translated words that was passed to the function 
    for item in text_to_trans: 
        display_words.append(item.text)
    textbox1 = Text(root2, height=10, width=20, font=("Arial", 20), bg='yellow')
    textbox1.pack()
    textbox1.insert(1.0, display_words)
```

My guess is that the issue is with the way that I am displaying the words on the screen (the `display_words` list), but I am unsure of a better way to do this to get the translated words.

EDITED: When I am getting instead is

uno dos tres.

Comment: You should not be creating a new root window. Create an instance of `Toplevel` instead.

Comment: Please explain what the issue is. Are you getting an error, and if so, what is the error?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited it for clarity. I will check it to Toplevel. The issue is that it is not coming out on a new line. Instead, it's just coming out 'uno dos tres'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly insert a newline between each element. The simplest way is with `join`:

```
textbox1.insert("1.0", "\n".join(display_words))
```